# Call Twig function with dynamic parameter

Tags: php, twig

I'm using Twig with [Slim](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim) and their [Twig-View](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View#custom-template-functions) view layer. This view layer has a function for creating URLs, which from the documentation looks like this:

```
{{ path_for('profile', { 'name': 'josh' }) }}
```

This works fine, but I have problems when the parameters are built with variables from dynamic data. For example this expression:

```
{{ path_for('profile', { 'name': '{{ PERSON.name }}' }) }}
```

Is simply evaluated as `{{ PERSON.name }}`. Twig does not parse the content of `{{ PERSON.name }}`, it just returns this as the value, so my URL looks something like `/path/to/profile/{{ PERSON.name}}`. If I move the expression outside my function call it is evaluated correctly.

I have looked at the [`attribute`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function, but can not figure out how to use this is my situation, as it seem more suited for calling functions dynamically on objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use vars inside your twig expression, you don't have to use the `{{.}}` syntax. Just write the plain var and it should work.

```
{{ path_for('profile', { 'name': PERSON.name }) }}
```

Comment: Boy do I feel stupid now. I was so sure that I tried this. I tried with the quotes, and it just gave me the string representation -- but no quotes worked like a charm. Thank you :)